# How to define unique constraint for scalar list?

Tags: database-design, database-schema, prisma, plumatic-schema

I created a scalar list `tags` in `Post` model. I want only unique tags in the list. How to do that?

Post model:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Prisma does not have support for this. This [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226456/how-can-i-get-a-unique-array-in-postgresql) has an answer that might interest you.